# Proof that if a linear map $T$ admits only $x=0$ as solution to $T(x)=0$, then $T$ is injective (one to one)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Theorem: Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation. Then if $T($**x**)=**0** has only **x**=**0**, $T$ is 1-1.

Proof Attempt (by contradiction):

Suppose not. Then $T($**x**)=**b** for more than one **x**. Let $T$(**u**),$T$(**v**) map to **b**, where **u**,**v** are unique.

Since $T$ is linear, $T$(**u**$-$**v**) = $T$(**u**) - $T$(**v**) = **b**$-$**b** = **0**.

Notice that **u** $\not=$ **v** (since they are unique) and therefore **u**$-$**v**$ \not=$**0**.

But, for $T$ to be 1-1: $T$(**u**) $-$ $T$(**v**) = **0** $\implies$ $T$(**u**) $=$ $T$(**v**) $\implies$ **u** $=$ **v** $\implies$ **u**$-$**v**$=$**0**. But since $T$ is linear, and therefore, $T$(**u**$-$**v**) = **0**, Contradiction. $T$ cannot be 1-1.

Therefore, **x** $=$ **0** must be the only solution to $T$(**x**)=**0** for $T$ to be 1-1.

Is this viable?

Comment: Looks fine. Alternatively you can use that the preimage of a singleton in a 1-1 function is also a singleton. Since $T(0)=0$ for all $T$ that singleton must be $\{0\}$.

Comment: The title asks for the opposite implication than the body of the question is about. Since the intention in the body is clear, I am going to change the title to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are unique.

Sorry, but this means nothing. What you want to say is that $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are *different*. So $\mathbf{u}\ne\mathbf{v}$ ***by assumption*** (and by way of contradiction) and does not follow from anything else.

After this, you lose yourself, I'm afraid.

From the assumption that $T(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{b}=T(\mathbf{v})$ you can deduce $T(\mathbf{u})=T(\mathbf{v})$. Then
$T(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{0}$. By the assumption on $T$, this implies $\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$, which contradicts $\mathbf{u}\ne\mathbf{v}$.

Actually, you don't need contradiction.

Suppose $T(\mathbf{u})=T(\mathbf{v})$. Then $T(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{0}$ by linearity and so, by assumption, $\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$. Therefore $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{v}$. This proves that $T$ is 1-1.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet a valid proof. You were supposed to show that if there are distinct $u,v$ such that $T(u)=T(v)$, then there is a $w\not =0$ such that $T(w)=0$. [You do note that $T(u-v)=0$ and that $u-v$ is nonzero, but then you just kept on going. Part of a valid proof is concluding properly.]

You were close though: If $T$ is not one-to-one, then by definition there exists two distinct vectors, $u$ and $v$, such that $T(u)=T(v)$. However: $$T(u)=T(v); \ u \not = v;$$  $$\implies T(u)-T(v) =0; \ u \not = v$$ $$\implies T(u-v)=0; \ u-v \not = 0.$$ Thus, if $T$ is not one-to-one, then there is a $w \not = 0$ such that $T(w)=0$, namely $w=u-v$. Thus as the contrapositive of this is equivalent, it is also true: If $T(w)=0$ only for $w=0$, then $T$ is on-to-one. [Edited to start from the beginning of the proof to the end.]

Comment: Edited: does it read more unequivocally now?

Comment: It is still an incorrect proof. You are not clear with precisely which direction you've just shown: If $T$ is not one-to-one then there is a nonzero $w$ such that $T(w)=0$. You instead concluded the converse: If there is a nonzero $w$ such that $T(w)=0$ then $T$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: I am trying to show ($\leftarrow$) I have edited my proof again.

Comment: But your second-to-last paragraph is hard to follow. In any event, the other side is easier to show: There is a $w \not = 0$ such that $T(w)=0$ $\implies$ $T(w)=T(0)=0$ for some $w \not = 0$ $\implies$  there are $2$ distinct vectors, namely $w$ and $0$, that $T$ maps to the same vector $\implies$ by definition of one-to-one, that $T$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof in both directions:

(1)  Assume that $T(x)=0 \implies x=0$, then \begin{align}
 T(a)=T(b) & \implies T(a-b)=0 \\
           & \implies a-b=0 \\
           & \implies a=b \\
\end{align}
Therefore $T$ is one-one.

(I think this is what is asked to  be proved.)

(2) Conversely assume that $T$ is one-one, then
\begin{align}
T(x)=0 & \implies T(x)=T(0) \\
       & \implies x=0 \;\;\;\; \mathrm{ (because \;T\;  is \; one-one) }\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can apply a stronger theorem: Let $f:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear mapping, then $f(u)=f(v)\Longleftrightarrow u-v\in kerf$

sketch of proof: for $\Rightarrow$, $f(u-v)=f(u)-f(v)=0$

for$\Leftarrow$, $f(u)=f(v+u-v)=f(v)+f(u-v)=f(v)$ $\square$

Given this lemma, now if $f$ is injective, $u-v\in kerf\Rightarrow f(u)=f(v)\Rightarrow u=v$, in other words $u-v=0\Rightarrow kerf=\{0\}$